# Is the following inequality always true for matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, independence, matrix-rank

Suppose we have six matrices (whose sizes are chosen in such a way that all the matrix multiplications are defined in inequality (1) below) given as follows $$\mathbb{H_{31},V_1,H_{32},V_2,H_{41},H_{42}}.$$ Further assume that each of $\mathbb{H_{31},H_{32},H_{41},H_{42}}$ is full rank and all of their individual columns are independent of each other. This means that if we concatenate $\mathbb{H_{31},H_{32},H_{41},H_{42}}$ then the resulting matrix will be full rank. In this situation is the following inequality always true? $$\dim(\mathbb{V_1})\geq \dim(\mathbb{H_{31}V_1\cap H_{32}V_2})+\dim(\mathbb{H_{41}V_1\cap H_{42}V_2}).\tag{1}$$

Comment: What is the intersection of two matrices?

Comment: @Brahadeesh with slight abuse of notation it actually represent the intersection of the span of two matrices.

Comment: the column span or the row span?

Comment: @Brahadeesh its column span

Comment: Consider adding these details to the question itself. It would also help if you can show some context. As it stands, this question is too specialised to generate enough interest, in my opinion.